# How to fix warning : dynamic initialization is not supported for a function-scope static __shared__ variable?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cuda

I have a structure with trivial constructor like

```
struct TResult
{
    int field1, field2;

    __host__ __device__ TResult()
        : field1(0),
          field2(0)
    { }
};
```

and gathering code like

```
#define BLOCK_SIZE 128

__global__ void uniteResults(TResult *destResults, TResult *srcResults)
{
    __shared__ TResult sums[BLOCK_SIZE];

    sums[threadIdx.x] = TResult();
    //...
}
```

As I understand I implemented shared array's initialization correctly.
But I am getting

```
warning : dynamic initialization is not supported for a function-scope static __shared__ variable within a __device__/__global__ function
```

for the __shared__ line. Ok, it means constructor should be called, but Nvidia's compiler can't do this. How to implement this properly so everyone would be happy?

Comment: The obvious problem is which thread should run the constructor at definition? If they all do, then you have a memory race. The answer is to have a default constructible type. If you need initialisation, have a defined thread in each block call or perform it.

Comment: You can also switch to dynamically allocated shared memory (or even statically allocated of a base type like `char` with a `reinterpret_cast`) then do placement `new` from a single thread to initialize your objects, without having to change any of your class code.

Comment: Could you please write the code? \_\_shared\_\_ TResult sums[];?

Answer (score 2):

As @talonmies suggests, you need to help the CUDA compiler avoid the dilemma of "Which thread(s) initialize the array values?" . Even a trivial constructor like yours is insufficient for this to happen. Only the *default* constructor - when it means, effectively, non construction - works. So:

```
struct TResult
{
    int field1, field2;

    TResult() = default;
};
```

which is basically like saying:

```
struct TResult
{
    int field1, field2;
};
```

and you will have to dynamically initialize. Luckily for you though, your dynamic initialization code is [fine](https://godbolt.org/z/6bx73je8o) (as long as, indeed, the block dimensions are BLOCK_SIZE x 1 x 1).

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of one possible workaround using placement `new`:

```
#define BLOCK_SIZE 128
#include <new>
struct TResult
{
    int field1, field2;

    __host__ __device__ TResult()
        : field1(0),
          field2(0)
    { }
};
__global__ void uniteResults(TResult *destResults, TResult *srcResults)
{
    extern __shared__ TResult sums[];
    new(sums+threadIdx.x) TResult();
    __syncthreads();
}
```

The assumption in the above code is that you will call the kernel with an appropriate dynamically allocated shared memory size declaration:

```
uniteResults<<<blocks, BLOCK_SIZE, BLOCK_SIZE*sizeof(TResult)>>>(...);
```

There are many variations on this idea that are possible.